# What are prime number values of the trinomial $q(n) = n^2 + n + 41$? Assuming $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many integer values $n$ such that $q(n)$ is a prime number?
Numerical evidence points to a yes answer.

This is similar to Landau's 4th problem from 1912.
(The conjecture that there are infinitely many primes $p$ of the form $p=n^2+1 $?)
Of course, Landau did not have a computer.
Given n a positive number, for what values of $n$ is $q(n)=n^2 + n + 41 $ a prime number?
This is known as Prime-Generating Polynomial.

see link
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

also Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions

also my document on this quadratic polynomial

https://mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?p=581027#post581027

There are 3 .pdf files hosted at mersenne.org.  I characterize all the cases when n^2 + n + 41 can be a composite number.  Assuming positive integer n.

I show a data table, graph, and curve fit to characterize all the
cases when this trinomial is a composite number, up to a certain
numerical limit.

Also, I have found some algebraic factorizations for q(n)

https://sites.google.com/site/mattc1anderson/prime-producing-polynomial

A leading question is, "If we can know whenever n^2+n+41 is composite, what does that tell up about when that trinomial is a prime number?"

Let me know if there are any questions.

Matt

Comment: This is an open problem.

Comment: How can numerical evidence point to something in this case?

Comment: The Bunyakovsky conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture says that, if $f(n)$ is an irreducible polynomial with positive leading term and there is no modulus $M$ for which $f(n)$ is identically $0 \bmod M$, then $f(n)$ is prime infinitely often. The polynomial $n^2+n+41$ satisfies these criteria. But there is no polynomial of degree $\geq 2$ for which the Bunyakovsky conjecture has been proved.

Comment: I added a second file to my 'blog' at mersenneforum.org with power point slides.  We have an algebraic factorization.  Let f(n) = n^2 + n + 41.  Then f(x^2+40) = (x^2+x+41)*(x^2-x+41) and this is necessarily a composite number.

Comment: To find potential primes of the form $6j-1$ then $n^2 +n$ must be of the form $6k$. One can then solve the quadratic $n^2+n-6k=0$ to find the values of $n$ for potential primes. A different expression for primes of the $6j+1$ must be used.

Comment: @MarkSapir One can make a conjectural asymptotic for the number of $n< X$ with $n^2+n+41$ prime, find numerical evidence that this asymptotic holds, and observe that this asymptotic predicts that there are infinitely many prime values.

Comment: Numerical evidence does not give any evidence in many cases. For example the 4n+1 vs 4n+3 competition.

Comment: @MarkSapir The claim is not that numerical evidence gives a definitive proof, but rather that it gives *evidence*, i.e. makes one possibility more likely. Examples where numerical data is misleading don't mean it's not evidence, unless there are more of those than examples where numerical data gives the right procedure.

Comment: Furthermore the method I suggested in this case, of first make a prediction based on the best available heuristics, then use numerics to check how well the heuristics seem to hold in this case, would not run into trouble in the 4n+1 vs. 4n+3 case anyways.

Answer (score 11):

Since the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-163}]$ is a PID, it follows that a rational prime $p \neq 163$  may be expressed in the form $x^{2} + xy + 41y^{2}$ for rational integers $x$ and $y$ if and only if $p$ is a quadratic residue (mod $163$).(This is well-known). But, as you point out yourself, your question is comparable to asking how many primes $p$ have the form $n^{2} +1$ for integer $n$, which is well known to be open and Wojowu confirms in comments that your question is open too.

Later edit: I find it mildly interesting that the prime $p$ is expressible in this way (ie $p = n^{2}+n+41$) if and only if $p$ is expressible as the sum of four integer squares in one of the following ways: If $n$ is odd, we find that
$p = \left( \frac{n-9}{2} \right)^{2} + \left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)^{2} +\left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)^{2} + \left( \frac{n+9}{2} \right)^{2}$ and if $n$ is even we find that $p = \left( \frac{n-8}{2} \right)^{2} + \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)^{2} +\left( \frac{n}{2} \right)^{2} + \left( \frac{n+10}{2} \right)^{2}.$

Even later edit: For any prime $p \neq 41$ which is a quadratic residue (mod $163$), there is a unique integer $h$ with $1 \leq h \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$ such that $p$ divides $h^{2}+h+41$, and then $p$ is necessarily the largest prime divisor of $h^{2}+h+41.$ An inductive argument of a type which dates back to Euler and/or Fermat then shows that $p$ is necessarily of the form $x^{2}+xy+41y^{2}$ for integers $x$ and $y$, and allows you to explicitly determine $x$ and $y$, given such an expression for the other (smaller) prime divisors $q$ of $h^{2}+h+41$ (all of which are also necessarily quadratic residues (mod $163$)).